# passport.deserializeUser does not fire all the time on new requests

Tags: node.js, express-session

I know there are several questions posted with this title already. However, my situation is different because for the deserialize does not fire consistently. I have setup my code to redirect to landing or "/" page on successful login. Upon first login it does work. However, if I logout and try to log back in it throws as error saying req.user is not defined in the landing route. I spent some time debugging this and found out that the instances where req.user is undefined is caused by deserialize user not firing. Here is my code

passport.js

```
  passport.serializeUser((User, done) => {
    console.log(`Serializing User ${User.UserID}`);
    done(null, User); // this communicates with the cookie
   
  });

  // used to deserialize the user
  passport.deserializeUser(async (User, done) => {
    try {
      
      const user = await pool.query(`SELECT *from Users where UserID = '${User.UserID}'`);
      if (user.recordset.length !== 0) {
        
        done(null, user.recordset[0]);
      } else {
        console.log('Setting user to null');
        // User is either deleted from the database or the userID is edited
        done(null, null); // Next request should log them out
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

server.js

```
const MSSQLStore = require('connect-mssql-v2');
const sessionStore = new MSSQLStore(config);

sessionStore.on('sessionError', (error, _classMethod) => {
  // ... any error that occurs within a store method
  // classMethod will return the method name (get, set, length, etc)
  console.log(`sessionError: ${error}`);
});

sessionStore.on('error', (error) => {
  // ... connection error
  console.log(`sessionConnectionError: ${error}`);
});

sessionStore.on('connect', () => {
  // ... connection established
  console.log('Session store connected');
});

server.use(require('express-session')({
  name: 'session',
  store: sessionStore, // options are optional
  secret: keys.session.secret,

 
  cookie: {
    /// max age is 10 minute by default
    maxAge: 1 * 10 * 60 * 1000,
   
  },
  resave: false, // or true if you want to save the session even if it wasn't modified
  saveUninitialized: false, // or true if you want to save a new session that hasn't been modified
 
}));

// Configure global passport object
server.use(passport.initialize());
server.use(passport.session());

passportConfig(passport);
```

login route:

```
 router.post('/login/admin',  passport.authenticate('admin-login', {
      failureRedirect: '/login',
    }), async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        console.log(`In admin login post request. User ${req.user.UserID} logged in`);
        const redirectURL = await database.getDefaultRedirectURL(req.user.UserID);
        console.log('Redirecting to URl: ', redirectURL);
    
        res.redirect(redirectURL);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
      }
    });
    
router.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
  // Fix me flash is not working
  // req.flash('success', 'You are Logged Out');

  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    console.log('Session Destroyed');
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
  });

 
});
```

Landing page:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('Inside the landing page');
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
```

This is the screenshot from when it does work:

[image]

You can see the deserialize user firing and `req.isAutheticated()`  returning `true` . Now, without changing a single thing on the code, just doing logout and logging back in returns this:

[image]

Serialize user fires but unlike the previous steps the deserialize user never fires and req.isAuthenticated is therefore false. Now, sometimes if I login and logout a couple of times it works for 2-3 times but after that it does not. After this error if I refresh the browser page it now fires the desterilize function and everything works as expected:

[image]

I have used `cookie-session` all the time I have used Nodejs. But this time I want to keep track of unique sessions even if they are from the same user which is why I am trying to use express session instead.